# RecyclerView, item swiping, java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My task is to implement item horizontal item swiping in RecyclerView. I'm actually done with the task thanks to ViewPager source code and some other resources, but have problems with one scenario.

My SwipeableRecyclerView (SRV from now on) extends RecyclerView and implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener to perform the magic, which actually works. It also defines a custom interface, SwipeListener, which defines a few methods, most important (for this question) is 'onSwipe(View view, int position, boolean right)'.

My activity supplies an implementation of the interface to the SRV, and when a swipe is detected and the listener method fired, it does the following:

- moves the item/swiped view off the screen in the correct direction with 'view.animate().translationX(translationX)'
- the animation started above has a listener, which, in onAnimationEnd, removes the item at the specified position from the Adapter and calls adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
- the result is that the view disappears to the swiped side and then the recycler removes the row with its animations - all of this works very nice actually

A problem sometimes occurs when I swipe very quickly, as in while the first animation is not done yet, I start swiping another row. Sometimes, it creates 'holes' / phantom rows with no view; sometimes, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
```

and the stack trace shows that the adapter.notifyItemRemoved() is the method causing the exception.

For the exception problem, the sequence of events is the following (from my debug traces):

```
started  for position: 11
started  for position: 10
finished for position: 11
removing 11
removed  11
finished position: 10
removing 10
```

So, both finishing animations are started one after another, and when one of them removed its item and called notifyItemRemoved, the other one finished and called removing the item. I'm not really sure how this can be as all of it happens on the main thread, actually, but I guess the scrolling also is done in animation frames, and it somehow with the new calculations needed because of the second removal.

So, I'm in a pickle, I have no idea what to do about this one. Actually, I think the easiest thing should be to disable touches of the whole recycler view when an animation is started, and enable them again only after the scrolling was done. I fail to disable the SRV, though - I tried setEnabled(false), clickable, etc. but nothing works.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what eventually worked for me:

- add a swipingEnabled property to the SRV; when false, onInterceptTouchEvent just calls through to the parent implementation, effectively disabling item swiping
- add this code in the method which is responsible for handling the swipe gesture (like removing the entry etc.):

  ```
  swipeableRecyclerView.setSwipingEnabled(false);
  ```
- add this code near where the SRV is created:

  ```
  swipeableRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {

      @Override
      public void onRemoveFinished(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
          swipeableRecyclerView.setSwipingEnabled(true);
      }
  });
  ```

  This just extends the default item animator with an implementation of a method which is called when the remove animation is finished.

Now, my swipe-to-dismiss is 'serialized' and no exceptions occur.

Comment: I found using onMoveFinished is better as this takes into account the reshuffle after the item is removed.

Comment: Does this mean that, after onRemoveFinished() is done, a whole bunch of moves is performed? I assumed (maybe wrongly) that the removal encompasses the whole operation...

Comment: I tested it and it really is like this: after onRemoveFinished, there is a whole bunch of onMoveFinished calls. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for `mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().isRunning()`, a bit easier than the current answer. While `true`, `MotionEvent`s should not trigger any removal.

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work. I am still able to swipe two or more views so that their animations overlap, and this resulted in a crash. Agreed, there might be something wrong in the rest of my code, I will have too test more. Thank you for your post, though, I wasn't aware of the method you mentioned, and its sister which takes a listener - cool stuff.

Comment: Might be, this works for me. The animation seems to be triggered by adapter.notifyItemRemoved().

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work for me: when I detect the dismissal, in my solution (the surrogate flag) I immediately disable any other swiping and start the finishing animation, whose onAnimationEnd listener method removes the item and calls notifyItemRemoved(), causing the remove animation to start. The solution you propose introduces a very short window (from when my swipe finishing animation starts running until the notifyItemRemoved() method is called, starting the animation). (To be continued in another comment).

Comment: The time window is very short, but nonetheless I am still able to start swiping the second item before the notifyItemRemoved() of the first one has been called, which makes problems. In my solution, as I disable swiping as soon as the swipe gesture has been detected, it is impossible for the user to swipe again while the animation is running. It's very tricky.

Comment: I think both conditions are necessary. You should not listen for new swipe gestures as long as a previous swipe gesture is being carried on, AND you should not listen for new swipe gestures as long as the removal animation is on, i. e. ItemAnimator().isRunning() == true.

Comment: True, but, in my case described in the post below, only do I set swipable to true in the animator onRemoveFinished() method. For my use cases this is has been enough as I only had removals, but you are right in the general case - I will merge the two approaches. Thank you.